# How to connect a symfony application to Azure redis cache?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, azure-redis-cache, predis

The symfony application is currently connected to a redis cache in a docker container. I have created a new Redis Cache on Azure and I am trying to connect it to my symfony application which is running in another docker container. According to [symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/components/cache/adapters/redis_adapter.html), `redis://[pass@][ip|host|socket[:port]][/db-index]` is the format of the connection string which is present in the `.env` file. In my case it is:

```
REDIS_URL=redis://mypassword@myrediscache.redis.cache.windows.net:6380
```

The application is unable to connect to the redis server on Azure. The application uses `predis v1.1.1` There is a Cacheservice.php service where the predis client is being created.

```
$this->client  = new Predis\Client($this->containerInterface->getParameter('REDIS_URL'));
```

For the existing (redis in container) setup, it is working fine.

```
REDIS_URL = redis://redis:6379
```

But when I change it to `REDIS_URL=redis://mypassword@myrediscache.redis.cache.windows.net:6379`, the application is unable to connect. However, if I hardcode the connection values, in a service where the predis client is being created, the application is able to connect.

The below snippet is hard-coded to connect to port 6380 (SSL enabled)

```
$this->client = new Predis\Client([
            'scheme' => 'tls',
            'ssl' => ['verify_peer' => true],
            'host' => 'myrediscache.redis.cache.windows.net',
            'port' => 6380,
            'password' => 'mypassword'
            ]);
```

The below snippet is hard-coded to connect to port 6379 (non SSL)

```
 $this->client = new Predis\Client([
                'host' => 'myrediscache.redis.cache.windows.net',
                'port' => 6380,
                'password' => 'mypassword'
                ]);
```

Please help me to put these values in the `.env` file instead of hardcoding it. By the way, here are some additional places where redis is referred.
`snc_redis.yaml` file:

```
snc_redis:
    clients:
        default:
            type: predis
            alias: default
            dsn: "%env(REDIS_URL)%"
```

`services.yaml` file:

```
parameters:
    REDIS_URL: '%env(resolve:REDIS_URL)%'
```

I have enabled the 6379 port for the Azure redis cache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to connect by doing the following changes :-

In `CacheService.php` (In your case it may differ. Where the predis client is created and defined)

```
$host = (string)$this->containerInterface->getParameter('REDIS_HOST');
        $port = (int)$this->containerInterface->getParameter('REDIS_PORT');
        $password = (string)$this->containerInterface->getParameter('REDIS_PASSWORD'); 
        $this->client = new Predis\Client([
                'host' => $host,
                'port' => $port,
                'password' => $password,
                'scheme' => 'tls',
                'ssl' => ['verify_peer' => true]
            ]);
```

Do the following changes in `services.yaml`

```
parameters:
    REDIS_PASSWORD: '%env(resolve:REDIS_PASSWORD)%'
    REDIS_HOST: '%env(resolve:REDIS_HOST)%'
    REDIS_PORT: '%env(resolve:REDIS_PORT)%'
```

And last but not least, in the `.env`

```
REDIS_PASSWORD=mypassword
REDIS_HOST=myrediscache.redis.cache.windows.net
REDIS_PORT=6380
```

Note: 1) The password shouldn't be encoded into utf-8. You should use the same exact password(primary key that you obtain from the azure portal).
2) Also, if you are going to use the port 6379(non ssl port), remove the `scheme` and `ssl` options from the connection.

Also make sure to remove the `REDIS_URL` references from `services.yaml` and `.env` .

Hope this works for others as well :-)